# Error: Step implementation missing for: [step_definition] when trying to run a scenario using cucumber with cypress

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I tried to do a simple test to try how cucumber works with cypress, but I didn't manage to solve the problem described in the title.

***Bellow is my js file:***

```js
import {Given, When, Then} from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps"
 
Given('I am in the demo site',()=>{
 
    cy.visit("https://www.saucedemo.com/index.html");
 
})
```

**here is my feature file:**

```html
Feature: Login Feature
 
Scenario: Login Validation
 
Given I am in the Swag Labs login page
```

Here is a screenshot with the issue
[image]

In tried a lot of things, but I didn't manage to solve this issue.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Your js step definition `I am in the demo site` does not match your feature file's step `I am in the Swag Labs login page`.

Change one of them so they have the same text.

Comment: Yeah, that was. After a lot of time I didn't see. Thank you

Answer (score 23):

Finally, I have identified the solution.The issue is with the folder structure and naming conventions. Below are the two main rules we need to follow

1. Folder name and Feature file name should be the same
2. Feature file and step definitions should not be in the same folder ( `stepdefinations/ .js` file should always be in a folder which we have created earlier).

[image]

Comment: Please follow this official documentation link for more information https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Comment: I had the same problems . I changed the folder name and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your step definition file should be

```
import {Given, When, Then} from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps"

Given('I am in the Swag Labs login page',()=>{

    cy.visit("https://www.saucedemo.com/index.html");

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in the `package.json` with your custom path

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
   "step_definitions": "cypress/integration/features/step_definitions/**/"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create the file .cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json project directory

```
 {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "cucumberJson": {
        "generate": "true",
        "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
        "filePrefix": "",
        "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

- Create feature file with "user-story1.feature" //This should be out side the folder
- Create folder with name "user-story1"
- Create scenario.js file in the folder user-story1/scenario.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a long road.
First off all we are using YARN so you have to add pluginsFile, npm_dependencies to browserstack.json

```
  "run_settings": {
  "cypress_config_file": "./cypress.json",
  "pluginsFile": "cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "cypress_version": "7",
  "project_name": "My sandbox project",
  "build_name": "Build no. 1",
  "parallels": "5",
  "npm_dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.0.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Second element it's 1

create the file .cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json project directory

{
"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
"cucumberJson": {
"generate": "true",
"outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
"filePrefix": "",
"fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
}
}

Thanks a lot @Vinayak Shedgeri